# Windows Phone 8 development - Logging & IOC Design Patterns

Tags: c#, .net, logging, inversion-of-control, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone development, especially to WP8. I have some minor experience with developing with WPF and I tried some proof-of-concept solutions with WP7.

So far I have been digging around the WP8 and didn't come to any answer that is targeting logging/tracing on WP8 and some usage of IOC. I have been developing for Android and been using Guice with RoboGuice. I have experience with both Windsor and Ninject, but it seems that WP8 isn't supported by any of those yet.

- What is the suggested way to perform logging/tracing on WP8?
- What are the best development and design patterns that should be used?
- Is there any IoC or Service locator or any library targeting those features?

Can you suggest some good libraries/tools/frameworks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/) may be interesting for you.

Also as a starter ("just to have something") solution you can save trace data to IsolatedStorage and then share it on http://pastebin.com/ so that other can access it.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that. Sorry for improper question here.